# Website cannot be found

Tags: 2007, iis

I have installed SP 2007 where nine domains are being hosted. Everything has been working correct until now. Right now, some of the domains cannot be displayed. I tried to edit the site in designer but I'm getting an error: Default.aspx cannot be found.

Only Central administration site and one of the domains (web.company.com) are working correctly. IIS configuration looks fine, virtual directories are set correctly. What could happened? How can I fix it?

Comment: Did you check the host header of the sites in IIS? did u do an IISReset? can u give more info on the error you are receiving since there could be possibly many reason for this?

Comment: Everything has been working correct. Host Headers looks fine and I did IISReset.

Comment: How about authentication? Is it windows auth enabled? can u check that in IIS?

Comment: Windows auth is enabled. Anonymous acces ans basic auth are disabled